# Question was downvoted - is it appropriate for this venue?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, down-votes

Recently, the following question of mine was downvoted:

- [How much financial damage do people in the United States yearly incur because birds poo on their cars?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/157213/how-much-financial-damage-do-people-in-the-united-states-yearly-incur-because-bi)

I wonder whether (a) the question is appropriate for this Stack Exchange page, and (b) if I could improve upon the question itself, in case it is indeed appropriate.

Answer (score 4):

The comments on your question explain it, but to repeat.
It isn't  a personal finance question, it looks like research for a business.